# parse a text file in shell scripting

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I want to read a file and print it to stdout using shellscript . in python rsplit can do the job but i search and find awk but i cant understand .

file1:

```
#begin cow
Host cow
    HostName 172.18.0.10
    User root
    Port 22
#end cow
#begin dns2
Host dns2
    HostName 172.20.4.80
    User root
    Port 22
#end dns2
#begin dns1
Host dns1
    HostName 172.20.4.75
    User root
    Port 22
#end dns1
#begin dns3
Host dns3
        HostName 172.20.4.76
        User root
        Port 22
#end dns3
#begin dns4
Host dns4
        HostName 172.20.4.77
        User root
        Port 22
#end dns4
#begin dns5
Host dns5
        HostName 172.20.4.78
        User root
        Port 22
#end dns5
#begin dns6
Host dns6
        HostName 172.20.4.79
        User root
        Port 22
#end dns6
```

after parsing its turns to

```
Host: cow  Hostname: 172.18.0.10 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns2 Hostname: 172.20.4.80 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns1 Hostname: 172.20.4.75 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns3 Hostname: 172.20.4.76 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns4 Hostname: 172.20.4.77 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns5 Hostname: 172.20.4.78 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns6 Hostname: 172.20.4.79 User: root Port: 22
```

any one can help me about this 
thank you

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? In your title, you are asking for a solution using shell programming, but then you ask for help with an awk program. Also, it is not clear, where exactly your problem ist. First I thought, you have problems collecting the lines belonging to one host, but then you explicitly mention `rsplit`. What exactly do you need to know? How to implement `rsplit` in awk? If yes, which awk are you using (old awk, gawk, ....)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your text (assume structure are complete (begin -> end), there is no empty line, ...)

```
awk -v "Sep=\t" '/^#begin/{Infos="";next}/^#end/{print Infos;next}{Infos = Infos ($1~/^Host$/ ? "" : Sep) $1 ": " $2}' YourFile
```

`Sep` is your separator between info sub sequence.

Same with a filter (only print if filter is the same; here if host is *cow* or *boy*)

```
awk -v "Sep=\t" -v"Filter=^cow$|^boy$" '
   /^#begin/{Infos="";PassFilter=0;next}
   /^#end/&&PassFilter{print Infos;next}
   $1~/^Host$/{PassFilter=$2~Filter}
   {Infos = Infos ($1~/^Host$/ ? "" : Sep) $1 ": " $2}
   ' YourFile
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^#begin/{Infos="";next}`  reset string to print every line starting by `#begin, go to next line of source file (don't treat following instruction).
- `/^#end/&&PassFilter{print Infos;next}` when line start with `#end` and the variable `PassFilter` is true (=1), print the string content of `Infos`, go to next line of source file.
- `$1~/^Host$/{PassFilter=$2~Filter}` when line first word is `Host`, the variable `PassFilter` is set to true if second word contains/corresponds to the regex into `Filter` variable (`^cow$|^boy$` in this case).
- `{Infos = Infos ($1~/^Host$/ ? "" : Sep) $1 ": " $2}` Add content of the current line (first (`$1`) then  `:` and finally second word in fact) to variable `Infos` with a separator `if not line with`Host` as first word.

Comment: Thank you its very helpful but how can i control tabs  between parameters

Comment: if i want to print only one block from this file like cow what awk command can i use ?

Comment: You need to add a filter  on block . In this structure best if before printing. 2 choice, filter the block or in the block. I show sample inside the block (easy to adapt)

Comment: can you give me a sample please i can figure out

Comment: with some basic explaination

Comment: i decided to remove #begin and #end so how can i change the command to parse from beginning of Host and end to beginning of another Host means a block like Host dns2
    HostName 172.20.4.80
    User root
    Port 22

Answer (score 5):

Since you haven't mentioned your `awk` command in the question, i assume u are looking for a solution with `awk` and an explanation.

```
AMD$ awk '!/^#/{printf $1": "$2" "}/end/{print '\n'}' File

Host: cow HostName: 172.18.0.10 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns2 HostName: 172.20.4.80 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns1 HostName: 172.20.4.75 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns3 HostName: 172.20.4.76 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns4 HostName: 172.20.4.77 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns5 HostName: 172.20.4.78 User: root Port: 22
Host: dns6 HostName: 172.20.4.79 User: root Port: 22
```

For all lines `NOT` beginning with `#` (`!/^#/`), printf the `1st` and `2nd` fields seperated by `:` and `space`. Continue this until we hit the `end` pattern (`/end/`), where we would print the new line.

In case you are looking for an explanation for the `awk` command you already have, mention it in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me can you please if i want to print only one block from this file like cow what awk command can i use ?

Comment: Arash Shams : awk '/#begin cow/{v=1}!/^#/&&v{printf $1": "$2" "}/end/&&v{print '\n';v=0}' File . You can upvote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: i decided to remove #begin and #end so how can i change the command to parse from beginning of Host and end to beginning of another Host means a block like Host dns2 HostName 172.20.4.80 User root Port 22